# firefox cannot load HTML and tells to save "untyped binary data"

Tags: html, firefox, dom, header, flash

In our website,a media file is being played in the HTML when it loads with the help of flash. We encounter a problem in firefox when autoplay is enabled. 
It seems that when the HTML loads some binary data from streaming corrupts the HTML header and hence is not able to detect the MIME-TYPE and so asks to save UNTYPED-BINARY data.

How do i solve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is sending the wrong MIME-type. The best suggestion I could give would be to make sure that the MIME types are set up correctly on the server.
Plus make sure that you have Flash player installed for firefox. Place flashplayer detection in your code: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html

Comment: One thing I will like to point is, if I do not pass argument "autostart=yes" in the flash object, thye media file is not played immediately when html page is loaded and the problem does not occur. It only occurs when I pass this argument and so in other browsers the media file will play as soon as html page is loaded. but in firefox due to some reasons it gives problem. (I tried to save the untyped binary data to only see that some binary data perhaps from song file was coming before html headers!!)